# Assembly: Using 4eh and 4fh to print a list containing the files in a directory

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, x86-16

I've created a program that contains different functions, depending on what key press I do. My program creates a folder and then a .txt file inside that folder. I want to show an updated list of the .txt files inside the folder as I add more and check it.

However, when I run my program, it shows only the latest .txt file created. How can I resolve this and show the list of all .txt files?

declared variables:

```
file_spec db "*.*", 0
DTA db 128h dup(0)

dirlist proc near
        mov dx,offset DTA
        mov ah,1ah
        int 21h
        mov dx,offset file_spec
        xor cx, cx
        mov ah,4eh
        int 21h
        call print_name 
        call next_char
        ret
    dirlist endp

    print_name proc near
        mov dx,10
        lea si, DTA + 1eh
        ret
    print_name endp

    next_char proc near
        lodsb
        int 29h
        test al, al
        jnz next_char
        mov al, 13
        int 29h
        mov al, 10
        int 29h
        mov dx, offset file_spec
        xor cx, cx
        mov ah, 4fh
        int 21h
        jnc print_name
        ret
    next_char endp
```

Comment: what does "file_spec" look like? have you tried `db "*.txt",0` ?

Comment: Your code flow seems wrong. `jnc print_name` will go to `print_name`, set `dx` and `si` and return to `dirlist` which then ends. You do not loop through the files.

Comment: @Jester How do I loop through the files? Sorry, I am not yet much familiar to all functions.

Comment: @Tommylee2k I'll try using it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code flow seems wrong. `jnc print_name` will go to `print_name`, set `dx` and `si` and return to `dirlist` which then ends. You do not loop through the files.

A modification that makes sense to me is to turn `next_char` into a simple label inside `print_name` instead of a standalone procedure. Also, putting the `find_next` inside `print_name` is bad coding practice. Something like this might work:

```
file_spec db "*.*", 0
DTA db 128h dup(0)

dirlist proc near
    mov dx,offset DTA
    mov ah,1ah
    int 21h
    mov dx,offset file_spec
    xor cx, cx
    mov ah,4eh
    int 21h
    jc done
next_name:
    call print_name 
    call find_next
    jnc next_name
done:
    ret
dirlist endp

print_name proc near
    mov dx,10
    lea si, DTA + 1eh

next_char:
    lodsb
    int 29h
    test al, al
    jnz next_char
    mov al, 13
    int 29h
    mov al, 10
    int 29h
    ret
print_name endp

find_next proc near
    mov dx, offset file_spec
    xor cx, cx
    mov ah, 4fh
    int 21h
    ret
find_next endp
```